How to connect the Ubuntu VM to WiFi
I installed a virtual machine using KVM, and both the host and guest are running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I'm able to ssh from the guest to the host, and the guest has internet access. So far so good!
Now I'm trying to cast a browser from the guest to my TV and need to first connect to the WiFi. However, the WiFi settings say that there is no WiFi adapter. Anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you!


Casting usually works only when devices are on the same subnet. Look at the IP addresses of the VM Guest (NOT the Host) and the TV. Are they on the same subnet?

@user535733 They weren't. I tried to get the VM on WiFi so they would be on the same subnet, but it keeps defaulting to the wired connection and won't use the WiFi.

Change the networking on your VM Host application (KVM on the host) from NAT to Bridged. NAT = A (virtual) router protecting your VMs, so different subnets. Bridged = VMs talk to the real LAN router, so same subnet.

@user535733 Don't see options for NAT and Bridged in network settings!
